# Oracle drop and create index

Tags: oracle, indexing

I would like to know if dropping Oracle index and recreating them will pose any data issues if assuming these are done during scheduled downtime.

Recently discovered that some indexes were parked on incorrect table space, would like to correct it by dropping the index and recreating it on the correct table space.

Please kindly advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see a problem with that, but instead of drop/create you could also use the syntax below:

```
alter index <INDEX_NAME> rebuild tablespace <TABLESPACE_NAME>
```

---

To address what you asked in the comment below, the `alter index rebuild` should be faster. The reason for that is when you drop the index and create it again, index tree will be built from the table itself. But with `alter index rebuild`, Oracle reads the index itself, thus resulting in a smaller amount of I/O.

Comment: Thanks. Will you think that an alter index will be much faster than a drop + create?

Comment: @ChinBoon, it should be roughly the same length of time. However, when re-building you lock the affected table so it can't be altered, or any integrity constraints violated as with drop / create.

Comment: Thanks once again. Once again, how can I know the rebuild is finished? Do I wait for the SQL statement to come back?

Comment: Yes, you should wait for it to come back.